# Download finished with wrong size - eclipse and android

Tags: android, eclipse

Downloading XOOM2ME, Android API 13, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 122780710 bytes, got 974 bytes.

Downloading OpenSense SDK for Tablets, Android API 12, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 3789731 bytes, got 94 bytes.

Downloading OpenSense SDK for Phones, Android API 10, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 7170813 bytes, got 93 bytes

I got these three errors.  There were no network disconnections.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Java SE 6

Thanks

Comment: How is this in any way related to a programming issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to be snarky. This is obviously related to programming if you can't download the tools you need to get the job done.

This thread indicates that you may have username/password issues since it appears that the result of 93 bytes means wrong username / password. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25294

So make sure your account is set up and you've entered your login information to be used during the download.  A dialog should pop up for you to enter the info during the download.

Still trying to figure out what my 91 and 92 byte results mean...Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

it means your internet connection is not fast or has datalost.

try to download directly using download managers.

To download platforms and apis which are from google.

1. open SDK Manager

Copy the first statusbar address to browser    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml or   http

1. To download other manufactories apis

SDK Manager > tools > Manage Add-on Sites

copy needed address to browser

and find your package download address.

1. If the address was just a file name Like(android-3.0-windows.zip) replace file name with xml file of apis in addressbar Like (dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml) to http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.0-windows.zip
2. **Make Sure the Protocol is NOT https**

download the file.

next create a folder in android installed dir (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) and rename it to "temp". put the downloaded zip file in temp folder and try to install using SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

As amac123 posted, everybody is having the problem: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25294

I have tweeted @HTCDev and have been giving them more information:
https://twitter.com/#!/JaredBanyard/status/192717262912892928

I am waiting to hear back.. Will keep you guys updated.  You can follow me at @JaredBanyard

[EDIT]
Okay, you should be able to access the SDK now.  It will ask you for a Username & Password.  Just use your Username/Password from http://www.htcdev.com .. if you don't have one, register!

Enjoy!
[/EDIT]